# Do markerlights put on a unit embarked in a dedicated transport remain on the passengers after the vehicle is destroyed?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tau

If I place markerlights on a unit that is inside their dedicated transport and subsequently destroy said transport, can I still use the remaining markerlights when I target the disembarked passengers with another unit in the same shooting phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The markerlights are on the transport, not the unit inside. Remember they are separate units, and generally you can not target units inside a transport (template vs. open topped being the exception). Any markerlights on a destroyed unit are removed with the unit.

The only way that would be possible, is if the targeted unit had a way to embark during your shooting phase. To my knowledge that's not possible.

Note: In 8th edition, this is still true, except that there are no templates anymore.

Comment: asslum's correct - you cannot target the unit inside the transport. That said, there's nothing stopping you from targeting the unit with more markerlight's once the transport is destroyed...

Comment: I see. I thought that the troops and the dedicated transport formed a unit, hence my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Kenji - they do for selection and deployment purposes, but not for targeting